# Questions for Ubuntu Bash in Windows

Tags: discussion, windows

This forum is focus in use of Ubuntu. After the..... revolutionary..... move of Windows we can use Ubuntu bash in Windows. In this forum can we ask questions for Ubuntu bash on Windows?